# jQuery synchronous non-blocking ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, nonblocking

In my web application, I have a series of ajax calls that are fired rapidly. On the server, these need to be processed in the same order as they are sent from the client.

I have been using the `async: false` configuration in jQuery to do this. However this causes the GUI to become very sluggish while it blocks for calls to finish.  With `async: true` the GUI is responsive, but the requests are not always processed in order.

Is there an alternative *non-blocking* way to queue up ajax requests, so the next one is sent only after the previous one has finished?

NOTE:  I don't have a "list" of requests to process. The requests are generated on the fly, so I need to be able to stuff them into some sort of a FIFO queue when they are generated, then consume the queue with some process.

Comment: you can call each one when the previous one is finished.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done easily with [jQuery promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
function firstAjax() {
    return $.ajax({...});
}

function secondAjax() {
    return $.ajax({...});
}

firstAjax().pipe(secondAjax).pipe(...).done(function() {
    alert('all requests have successfully finished');
});
```

or

```
$.when(firstAjax()).pipe(secondAjax).pipe(...).done(function() {
    alert('all requests have successfully finished');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/WQcVD/1/

Comment: I think `done` could have arguments `.done(function(a1,  a2){...})`

Comment: @Sheikh Heera: yep, but I cannot get how it's possible to do that for all deferreds (in case if we chain them, not run simultaneously). If only we pass manually `arguments` in `secondAjax`

Comment: OK, the problem is I don't "have" all the calls I'm going to make when this process starts...

Comment: @bradvido: then create some sort of "global" object and `.pipe()` requests to it as soon as you have another request http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/WQcVD/3/

Comment: @pimvdb: look at the comment above: "OK, the problem is I don't "have" all the calls I'm going to make when this process starts" --- so OP doesn't have all the deferreds in one place, so he needs to be able to add piped requests (that's actually why I didn't use a single `$.when()`

Comment: Ah, my apologies. (I thought just wrapping the first call with `$.when` isn't very useful.)

Comment: @pimvdb: no worries :-) Thanks for making answers even more helpful! ;-)